# Ciclical Function

Tags: functions

I'm trying to solve a problem which I can't figure out by myself. I don't know even if it have a specific name, I called Ciclical Function because I don't know, so sorry if I haven't found anything here yet. It' basically a function that works this way:

```
f(0) = 13
f(1) = 14
f(2) = 15
f(3) = 16
f(4) = 17
f(5) = 18
f(6) = 19
f(7) = 20
f(8) = 21
f(9) = 22
f(10) = 23
f(11) = 24
f(12) = 25
f(13) = 0
f(14) = 1
f(15) = 2
f(16) = 3
f(17) = 4
f(18) = 5
f(19) = 6
f(20) = 7
f(21) = 8
f(22) = 9
f(23) = 10
f(24) = 11
f(25) = 12
```

It seems to be simple, but I couldn't find a solution. I tried using `modulus` operator or absolute (`|x|`), but still couldn't figure. What's the best solution for this?

Comment: $f(x)=x+13$ mod($26$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be $$x+13 \;(\text{mod }26)$$